# Prove that: $(x_1+...+x_k)^2\leq 2(x_1^2+...+x_k^2)$.

Tags: inequality

Prove that:
$$(x_1+...+x_k)^2\leq 2(x_1^2+...+x_k^2)$$
for all $x_1$, ... $x_k\in\mathbb R$. Is it also true that
$$\left|x_1+...+x_k\right|^2\leq 2(|x_1|^2+...+|x_k|^2)$$
for all $x_1$, ... $x_k\in\mathbb C$?

My attempt for $k=2$.
$$(x_1-x_2)^2\geq 0, \ \ \Rightarrow\ \ x_1^2+x_2^2\geq 2 x_1x_2$$
Then $(x_1+x_2)^2=x_1^2+x_2^2+2 x_1x_2\leq x_1^2+x_2^2 + x_1^2+x_2^2$ so I think we can prove the first statement by the induction principle. Is true the second statement?

Comment: This is not true $x_1=x_2=x_3=1$ and the rest equal to zero, gives $9\leq 6$.

Comment: The best you can do is $(x_1+\cdots+x_k)^2\le k(x_1^2+\cdots+x_k^2)$. You get this from Cauchy-Schwarz using the all ones vector as the other vector. C-S is tight in the known cases, so....

Comment: This seems to be only true for $k = 2$. 
By Cauchy-Schwarz's inequality, we have:
$\left(\sum_{j=1}^{k} x_{j} \right)^{2} \leq k \sum_{j=i}^{k}x_{i}^{2}$.